# Android and Apple apps how does they communicate?

Tags: android, ios

I just would like to know how the two platforms are communicating with each other, let me come with an example lets take the app like Tinder, you can get the app for Android and iPhone, and people who are using Android can match with people on iPhones.

Am I just overthinking the concept and is just SQL Databases or how does it work?

A head Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar to asking how different brands of TVs can all display the same content. All the data in these apps is stored in the companies' databases. Their IOS and Android apps simply act like the television screens, displaying the data from these databases.

Every time you make a change to your profile or interact with anything, this information is sent back to the server and updated.

This way, every time you access your profile on a different device, all your information remains the same.
No matter what platform (IOS or Android) is being used, the same process takes place, and the same data is displayed.

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot I don't know why I was over thinking this so much.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, The devices (whether android or iOS) respectively communicate with the database, which then communicates back to the devices.

If we look at tinder's case,

1. I (android device) swipe right
2. The database gets the appropriate data
3. The database then does some magic and communicates to my fantasy girlfriend (iOS) device
4. Her iOS app runs it's iOS logic to get the her to receive that notification